# Issue with NSURLSession returning tuple

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift2

I do a request on a website and I want to return 3 Strings but I get this Issue :

> Tuple types '(StringLiteralConvertible, StringLiteralConvertible, StringLiteralConvertible)' and '()' have a different number of elements (3 vs. 0)

That is how my code looks like :

```
func downloadContent() -> (title : String, message : String, buttonText : String)? {
    let url = NSURL(string: websitePath)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)

            return ("", "", "")
        }

    }

    task.resume()

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code has error in it. If you look at it carefully you are returning from inside a closure which expects a return value of Void. That is what the error is about,

```
'(StringLiteralConvertible, StringLiteralConvertible, StringLiteralConvertible)' and '()'
```

The type '()' means it is a void type that is expected.

So, where is your mistake,

In your dataTaskWithURL method, the closure looks like this,

```
{ (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil{
            print(error?.localizedDescription)

            return ("","","")
        }
    }
```

The closure expects the Void type to be returned, but you return tuple of string.

One of the thing that is bad about the code above is about asynchronous code execution. The dataTask runs asynchronously and returns immediately, so you cannot return value of it. You should rather use some completion block to get the result after the call has completed.

I would suggest you to restructure it it the following,

```
func downloadContent(completion: (title : String, message : String ,buttonText : String)? -> Void){
    let url = NSURL(string: websitePath)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil{
            print(error?.localizedDescription)
        }

        completion((title: "", message: "", buttonText: ""))
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`NSURLSession` works in background, so you need a callback function:

```
func downloadContent(callback: (title: String?, message: String?, buttonText: String?) -> Void) {
    let url = NSURL(string: websitePath)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
            print(error?.localizedDescription)

            callback(title: "", message: "", buttonText: "")
        }

    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The statement `return ("","","")` returns from the closure  not from the `downloadContent()` function.

Since the closure definition declare a `Void` – i.e.: `()` – return type, the compiler complains using the error message you are receiving.